# I can't understand how express.js code works. There is no declare vars "router"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I’m analyzing express.js code, I think next variable(object) is no declared but the code is working.
So any kind person can tell me?

[lib/router/index.js#L47](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/index.js#L47)

```
function router(req, res, next) {
  router.handle(req, res, next);
}
```

I can't find where declared ***router***.handle. ***router*** is never declared outer function.
So please tell me why the code works.

At first, I thought same question next code. 
[lib/express.js#L39](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/express.js#L39)

```
var app = function(req, res, next) {
  app.handle(req, res, next);
};
```

but I found it is declared.
[lib/application.js#L38](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L38)

```
var app = exports = module.exports = {};
```

Of course, I feel something strange that why function name is same as variable(object) name.
Can anyone tell me?

I use vue.js in my work. so, I think I’m intermediate level of JavaScript.

Comment: It's declared here https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/e1b45ebd050b6f06aa38cda5aaf0c21708b0c71e/lib/router/index.js#L136

Comment: Thank you for replying. but I don't understand reading order. I'll try more study.